# Android Move Object Randomly

Tags: android, animation

I want to implement a gaming scenario where a ball keeps moving continuously, hitting and bouncing off the wall.

How can I implement this, taking into account that path should be random?

I tried `ObjectAnimator`, but which always require an x or y coordinates specified.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you include any code?

Comment: Thanks Daniel,I have not started with coding yet ,I need a start.I want to move a ball randomly on screen which bounces off when hits wall,it should keep looping that way.

Comment: @DanielV How do you do it?